# concatenating data frames python

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation

I need to concatenate 6 data frames and csv file names are stored as 'all_files'. I have the following code:

```
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, encoding = 'utf-8') for f in all_files)
data = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
```

It gives the following error:

First line works well, but second line gives this error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 1: invalid start byte

I tried different encodings but still gives the error. Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Looks like you need to try more encodings. What about `cp1252`, `cp1251`?

Comment: Those give errors as well: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @koPytok, I updated the question, the second line gives the error.

Comment: Did you try encoding='latin-1' ? Also, pd.concat needs axis=0 or 1.

Comment: @Rubens_Z, 'latin-1' worked, thank you all guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user229519, use `encoding='latin-1'` for `pd.read_csv` and also `axis=0` or `1` for `pd.concat`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the separator, try either of these:

```
pd.read_csv(f,sep = ';')
pd.read_csv(f,sep = ',')
```